# Any way to save and recover undo history in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

When you run a VBA macro under Excel, it erases the undo history.  Is there any way to prevent this?  I'd like to capture the undo history before running my macro, and restore it after my macro is finished.  I didn't notice anything in the Excel documentation that looked promising.

Comment: Hard to see how this would work -- what if your macro has changed something in the file?  Now the previously stored undo commands are operating on a file that's different from what was done.  E.g., if you have "foo" in a cell, and you erase it, and then the macro deletes that column, and then you click "undo", what should happen?

Comment: See here http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-288722.html

Comment: Thanks, some good tips in that thread.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to keep undo history in an Excel macro (there is in a Word macro, so VBA itself has the hooks, which makes it a confusing business). Whenever the VBA launches, Excel kills the undo stack.